# Scaffold-DbContext Error "Login failed for user MicrosoftAccount\my_email@gmail.com"

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Trying to execute this command in Visual Studio Package Manager Console:

`Scaffold-DbContext "Server=my_server\SQLEXPRESS;Database=FoodStore;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models`

but I'm getting this error:

> Cannot open database "FoodStore" requested by the login. The login
>   failed. Login failed for user 'MicrosoftAccount\my_email@gmail.com'.

I've tried creating a login in Security for 'MicrosoftAccount\my_email@gmail.com' as db_owner in Microsoft SQL Management Service Studio, as well as signing in with local accounts instead, but I'm still getting an error in Visual Studio when running Scaffold-DbContext.

Comment: Did you create a user in the FoodStore DB for the MicrosoftAccount\my_email@gmail.com account with appropriate permissions? You cite the db_owner permissions, but it is unclear from your post what database you granted those permissions in.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same error but Ifound the solution. In scaffolding string I am using the server name "LAPTOP-82GAEQ6T\SQLEXPRESS" but in SQL server I am using only "LAPTOP-82GAEQ6T". That's the same error I was facing, please check your server connection name on both sides, on the server side and your connection string. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue as you have mentioned i.e.

Cannot open database "dbxxxxx" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'xxxxx\xxx'.

And after working around with it, I found that I had to carefully check the value of 
 **server** attribute.

[image]

"Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=FoodStore;Trusted_Connection=True;" also works well.